# Save state of checkbox in gridview when changed to edite mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I am clicking on imagebutton in my gridview, some cells become editable
but, it loses all the checkboxs values that in the gridview.

Is there a way to save these values?

I made a function who gets the checkboxes values from my xml but, when I call the function inside the command era it's not working.

When I call that function in other imagebutton command era in the gridview which doesn't make some cells editable, that works and the function runs and the values from the xml shown on the checkboxes.

Thanks

```
<asp:GridView style="direction:rtl; " ShowHeader="False" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#926c3f" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" RowStyle-BorderColor="White" ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowEditing="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowSorting="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" שם משחק" ItemStyle-Width="200px" >
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Server.UrlDecode(XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "gameName").ToString())%>'> </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="nameTB" runat="server" Text='<%#Server.UrlDecode(XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "gameName").ToString())%>'> </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="קוד משחק" ItemStyle-Width="85px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="codeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Server.UrlDecode(XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "gameCode").ToString())%>'> </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="הגדרות" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="cancelImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" CommandName="cancel" OnClientClick="showWhoIsPublish" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="approveImageButton" theItemId='<%#XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "@id")%>' runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/approve.png" CommandName="approve" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton  ID="settingsImageButton" runat="server" CssClass="buttons" ImageUrl="~/images/אייקון הגדרות.png" theItemId='<%#XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "@id")%>' CommandName="edit" OnClientClick="showWhoIsPublish" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="עריכה" ItemStyle-Width="70px" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="editImageButton" runat="server" CssClass="buttons" ImageUrl="~/images/אייקון עריכה.png" theItemId='<%#XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "@id")%>' CommandName="editQ" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="מחיקה" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteImageButton" CssClass="buttons" OnClick="doDelete_Click"  theItemId='<%#XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "@id")%>' runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/אייקון מחיקה.png" CommandName="deleteRow" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" הגבלת זמן" ItemStyle-Width="90px" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListT"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem> 10 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem> 20 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem> 30 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem> 40 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> 50 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem> 60 שניות</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                         </EditItemTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID="Time" runat="server" Text='<%#Server.UrlDecode(XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "time").ToString())%>'> </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="פרסום" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox1" CssClass="buttons1" theItemId='<%#XPathBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "@id")%>' AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="PublishYesNo_CheckedChanged" ViewStateMode="Inherit" EnableViewState="True" Checked="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    showWhoIsPublish();

    ImageButton i = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
    // אנו מושכים את האי די של הפריט באמצעות מאפיין לא שמור במערכת שהוספנו באופן ידני לכפתור-תמונה
    string theId = i.Attributes["theItemId"];
    Session["theId"] = theId;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = XmlDataSource1.GetXmlDocument();

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        //אם נלחץ על כפתור מחיקה יקרא לפונקציה של מחיקה
        case "deleteRow":
            popOfDelete.Visible = true;
            string deleteId = (string)Session["theId"];

            string theGameNameDelete = Server.UrlDecode(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//game[@id='" + (string)Session["theId"] + "']/gameName").InnerXml);
            nameOfGameDelete.Text = "'" + theGameNameDelete + "' " + "?";
            showWhoIsPublish();
            break;

        case "editQ":
            string editId = (string)Session["theId"];
            string theGameNameEdit = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//game[@id='" + (string)Session["theId"] + "']/gameName").InnerXml;
            Session["nameOfEdit"] = theGameNameEdit;
            Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx");
            break;

        case "edit":
            addNameTB.Text = "jg";
            showWhoIsPublish();
            break;

        case "cancel":
            GridView1.DataBind();
            showWhoIsPublish();
            break;

        case "approve":

            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(i.Parent.Parent);
            string ApproveId = (string)Session["theId"];
            int index = gvRow.RowIndex;

            string myName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("nameTB")).Text;
            string myValue = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("DropDownListT")).Text;
            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//game[@id='" + ApproveId + "']/gameName").InnerText = Server.UrlEncode(myName);
            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//game[@id='" + ApproveId + "']/time").InnerText = Server.UrlEncode(myValue);
            XmlDataSource1.Save();
            // יציאה ממצב של עריכה
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            // ריענון הגריד ויו
            GridView1.DataBind();
            showWhoIsPublish();
            break;


    }
}

 protected void showWhoIsPublish()
{
    //סימון מה שמפורסם
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = XmlDataSource1.GetXmlDocument();
    XmlNodeList myListPublish = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/games/user[@id='" + Session["id"] + "']/game/@isPublish");

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Checkbox1");

        if (myListPublish.Item(i).InnerXml == "yes")
        {
            chkItem.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chkItem.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a PostBack Issue.. are you checking the IsPostBack on the Page_Load event..? also you could save the values in a Session Object.. you could also write some javascript code to handle this as well in the `__DoPostBack` Function

Comment: its in the load but if it runs with every load its not leting me to uncheck the checkbox (becouse load happens before the code in the checkbox SelectedIndexChanged). I can save them with sessions but i am looking for a shortet way.